# Improvement proposal for my hadoop architecture

Tags: hadoop, architecture, hortonworks-data-platform

I want to build a big data environment based on Hortonworks but I'm not so familiar with all the great tools. Many tools are very similar, but the devil is in the details. Maybe you can help me to validate my thoughts so I can start with a solide base.

I want to connect the following data resources to hadoop:
 - Twitter Stream
 - Chat
 - Boards
 - ...

With a REST API I want to search for single words per stream or in all stream. There should also be the option to search in the whole dataset or only in the past 24h. The methodes (UseCase) could be:

- findwordintwitter
- findwordinchat
- ...
- findwordintwitter24h
- findwordinchat24h
- ...
- findwordinallstreams
- findwordinallstreams24h

The idea was to use Flume, hbase and KNOX. But is it so simple? Flume will put the data into hbase and I can get my information through REST. KNOX will secure the in- and outgoing connections. But I think, that I miss a lot and it is not so simple like I mention.

Maybe I need a pipeline like Kafka for each UseCase, or one hbase instance per stream. I am struck by the large number of tools and I hope that someone can give me a hint which tools I need. A little architecture overview with a explanation would be great, so I get a clue to build on it.

thanks, n3

Answer (score 0):

@n3 - This is a difficult question for someone to quickly answer for you. I think that what you describe is certainly one way to accomplish what you have in mind. I can tell you that the Knox API Gateway is certainly a good way for accessing HTTP resources from outside the cluster.

You might also want to consider:

- Nifi - for ingest of twitter streams, etc
- Storm - for similar ingest with pipelines
- kafka - for scalability of ingest streams
- solr/solrcloud - for search capabilities

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the last days, I figure out that this topic is very komplex and not easy to answer. But thank you for the hints.